Using generics to make an argument optional
I have a type as follows:
type EventType = {
  event1: undefined,
  event2: {
    user: number
  }
}

type EventName = keyof EventType;

That type is used to type a logEvent function:
function logEvent<T extends EventName>(eventName: T, extraData: EventType[T]) {

}

This ensures that when logEvent is called, the correct combination of eventName and extraData is enforced:
logEvent('event1', undefined)
logEvent('event2', { user: 5 })

However, for the first case (undefined) i would like the second argument to be optional:
logEvent('event1')
logEvent('event2', { user: 5 })

I'm struggling to find a solution to this. My attempts are mostly nonsense.

I don't know if I understand. Would you like to have the second parameter optional? Something like: function logEvent<T extends EventName>(eventName: T, extraData?: EventType[T])

@ema I only want it to be optional for cases of T where EventType[T] is undefined

@jcalz I made a mistake there. Fixed!

There are different ways to proceed. You could generic conditional types as shown in this playground link. Or you could use overload as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate. If not, what's missing?

@jcalz Yes that's perfect, thank you!

Unfortunately TypeScript does not automatically treat trailing parameters that accept undefined as optional. There's a feature request for this at microsoft/TypeScript#12400, but it's not part of the language as of TypeScript 5.6.
If you want behavior like this you'll need to write it yourself. There are a bunch of ways to do this, assuming you want to keep this as a generic function. Here are two:

One approach is to use a conditional type to operate on the tuple type of trailing parameters. Here's one way to do that:
type UndefinedToOptional<T extends any[]> =
  { [I in keyof T]: undefined } extends T ? Partial<T> : T

The mapped type {[I in keyof T]: undefined} looks like T but with every element undefined. So if T is [x: string | undefined, y: number], then the mapped type looks like [x: undefined, y: undefined].  The conditional type checks if that mapped type is assignable to T.  If it is, then the whole thing might as well be optional, as represented by Partial<T>. If not, then it cannot be optional (at least not the whole thing).  So if we do that to your function, we get:
type EventType = {
  event1: undefined,
  event2: {
    user: number
  }
  event3?: {
    id: string;
  }
}

declare function logEvent<K extends keyof EventType>(
  eventName: K,
  ...rest: UndefinedToOptional<[extraData: EventType[K]]>): void;

Where the [extraData: EventType[K]] rest tuple will be transformed to [extraData?: EventType[K]] when EventType[K] accepts undefined. Let's test it:
logEvent('event1', undefined) // okay
logEvent('event1'); // okay
logEvent('event2', { user: 5 }) // okay
logEvent('event2'); // error
logEvent('event3', { id: "abc" }); // okay
logEvent('event3'); // okay


Or you could write overloads instead, if you don't want to mess with rest tuples. You still need some kind of conditional type to compute which things are optional. For your code it might look like:
type UndefinableKeys<T> = (keyof T) & { 
  [K in keyof T]: undefined extends T[K] ? K : never 
}[keyof T]
type UndefinableEvents = UndefinableKeys<EventType>;
//   ^? type UndefinableEvents = "event1" | "event3"

Here UndefinableKeys<T> returns the subset of the keys of T for which undefined is assignable to the corresponding property. Then you can just make two call signatures, one for each way to call it:
declare function logEvent<K extends keyof EventType>(
  eventName: K, extraData: EventType[K]): void;
declare function logEvent<K extends UndefinableEvents>(
  eventName: K, extraData?: EventType[K]): void;

logEvent('event1', undefined) // okay
logEvent('event1'); // okay
logEvent('event2', { user: 5 }) // okay
logEvent('event2'); // error
logEvent('event3', { id: "abc" }); // okay
logEvent('event3'); // okay

Playground link to code

You may not want a generic function. Instead you may want a function where the parameter type is a union of tuples that represent all possible combinations of arguments you allow.
So you want a type like this:
type EventArgs =
  | [eventName: "event1"]
  | [eventName: "event2", extraData: { user: number }]

And now you use that type in your logEvent function like so:
function logEvent(...[eventName, extraData]: EventArgs) {
  console.log(eventName, extraData)
}

logEvent('event1') // fine
logEvent('event1', undefined) // type error

logEvent('event2') // type error
logEvent('event2', { user: 123 }) // fine

Now each event name is paired with the other arguments that particular event name needs.
See Playground

So then, how do you generate that EventArgs type from EventType?
With a mapped type that maps over each property of EventType and create the tuple needed for each one.  That might look like this:
type EventArgs = {
  [K in keyof EventType]:
    EventType[K] extends undefined
      ? [eventName: K]
      : [eventName: K, extraArgs: EventType[K]]
}[keyof EventType]

This maps over every property, and checks if the value of that property undefined. If it is undefined, then the tuple is just the key name as the one argument for the function. If is isn't undefined that use a tuple with 2 members, one for the key name, and one for the extraData.
See Playground

Also a great approach! I went with jcatz' answer ultimately but love this too

You can use conditional rest params:
Playground
declare function logEvent<K extends keyof EventType>(eventName: K, 
  ...args: undefined extends EventType[K] ? 
    [] | [undefined] | [Exclude<EventType[K], undefined>]: 
    [extraData: EventType[K]]
): void;

